# Synonym for "In the final phase of this study"

Tags: synonyms

Can anyone give me a synonym for the phrase "In the final phase of this study"?

I have already used this phrase in my paper and now I am looking for a synonym without losing the real meaning of the phrase.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Please elaborate. Why doesn't the current phrase work for you? What properties should the new one have?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Well, I just want to prevent word repetitions. Therefore, I am looking for a similar phrase.

Comment: So you don't care about redundancy in content (saying the same thing twice), but you care about redundancy of expression (using the same words twice)? Why is that? Why not drop the redundant content altogether?  Or just repeat the same words, if you want to repeat the content for effect. Or give that final phase a **name**, and use that. That has the advantage of communicating what the phase was about.

Comment: I am not saying the same thing twice. I use the phrase in the introduction and now I am asking for a similar phrase that I can use in my conclusions. However, the content is not related.

Comment: The phase after the penultimate one.

Comment: phase -> stage, part; final -> ultimate, last, finishing, final, end... Would any combination of those work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite a synonym but how about; in conclusion, to summarize, to cut a long story short, to sum it up, in the final run, finally, in the final lap grand finale, culmination, pinnacle, acme, end-game, consummation, wrap-up